# Handling event updates conflating the key to 1 sec using reactive extension

Tags: c#, events, system.reactive, reactive

I get an update event at the rate of 150-200 updates / second. I would like to conflate this to 1 second per key.

Example: In 1 second I receive updates for 3 keys A,B,C in the order of: A1, B1, C1, A2, A3, B2

I would like to handle this update every 1 second & process only A3, B2 & C1 from the above example.

How do I go about with this using Reactive extension?
So far I tried:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(_listener, "EventHandler", System.Reactive.Concurrency.NewThreadScheduler.Default)
            .GroupBy(x => x.EventArgs.Key)
            .Subscribe(g =>
            {
                g.Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                .Subscribe(x1 =>
                {
                    updateSubject.OnNext(key);
                });
            });
```

Certainly not what I'm expecting. Please suggest the right approach for this.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something more like this:

```
Observable
    .FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(_listener, "EventHandler", System.Reactive.Concurrency.NewThreadScheduler.Default)
    .GroupBy(x => x.EventArgs.Key)
    .Select(g => g.Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)))
    .Merge()
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        updateSubject.OnNext(key);
    });
```

However, it's a really bad idea to have `updateSubject.OnNext(key);` inside your `.Subscribe`. You really should show more of your code so that we can advise on how to handle that properly.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much I'm doing after that

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(_listener, "EventHandler", System.Reactive.Concurrency.NewThreadScheduler.Default)
            .GroupBy(x => x.EventArgs.Key)
            .Subscribe(g =>
            {
                g.Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                .Subscribe(x1 =>
                {
                    updateSubject.OnNext(key);
                });
            });

updateSubject
.SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
.ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
.Subscribe(EventHandler); //Event Handler is the what gets called to handle the events
```

The Merge did not do it for me, however I tried:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(_listener, "EventHandler", System.Reactive.Concurrency.NewThreadScheduler.Default)
            .Distinct(x => x.EventArgs.Key)
            .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Subscribe(x1 =>
            {
                    updateSubject.OnNext(x1.EventArgs.NewValue);
            });
```

Not sure if I'm doing it right here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom `SampleLatestByKey` operator that probably does what you want:

```
/// <summary>
/// Samples a sequence of key-bearing elements at a specific interval. Upon each
/// sampling tick an IDictionary<TKey, TSource> is emitted, containing the latest
/// values that were emitted by each key during the last sampling period.
/// </summary>
public static IObservable<IDictionary<TKey, TSource>> SampleLatestByKey<TSource, TKey>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    TimeSpan interval,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = default)
{
    return source
        .Window(interval)
        .SelectMany(window => window
            .Aggregate(new Dictionary<TKey, TSource>(keyComparer),
                (dict, x) => { dict[keySelector(x)] = x; return dict; }));
}
```

Usage example:

```
Observable
    .FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(_listener, "EventHandler")
    .SampleLatestByKey(x => x.EventArgs.Key, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
    .Subscribe(dict => dict.Keys.ToObservable().Subscribe(updateSubject));
```

A similar custom operator named `SampleByKey` exists in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823090/is-it-possible-to-sample-the-latest-item-in-a-hot-observable-grouped-by-key) question. The difference between the two operators is that the `SampleByKey` emits the latest values per key during the whole lifetime of the observable sequence. The `SampleLatestByKey` propagates instead only values that were emitted during the last sampling interval.