# Is it possible to sample the latest item in a hot observable grouped by key?

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

In Rx.NET, is it possible to sample the latest item in a hot observable grouped by key?

For example, if I have an `IObservable<Price>`, where `Price` is:

```
Price 
- Key
- Bid
- Offer
```

Let's assume that the `IObservable` is linked to an external price feed.

Am I able to retrieve all latest `Price`s, grouped by `Key`, sampled every 1 second using Rx?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Rx grouped throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694010/rx-grouped-throttling)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming some observable `source`, this returns all prices grouped and sampled by key that have come in in the last second.

```
var sampled = source
    .GroupBy(p => p.Key)
    .SelectMany(o => o.Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
```

If there's some price which hasn't received a message in the last second, that will not be included.

If you want old prices included, this will work:

```
var sampled2 = source
    .Scan(ImmutableDictionary<int, Price>.Empty, (state, p) => state.SetItem(p.Key, p))
    .Replay(1)
    .RefCount();
var dummySubscription = sampled2.Subscribe();
var result = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .SelectMany(_ => sampled2.Take(1).SelectMany(state => state.Values));
```

Just make sure to dispose of the `DummySubscription` when done with the `result` observable.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I also include prices that were received more than a second ago?

Comment: Updated Answer.

Comment: Very nice! Two possible improvements: `AutoConnect(0)` instead of `RefCount`+`dummySubscription`, and adding `.TakeUntil(sampled2.LastOrDefaultAsync())` at the end so that the resulting sequence completes when the `source` completes.

Comment: AutoConnect didn't exist when this was written. :)

Comment: Maybe this answer was the motivation to introduce this operator. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
IObservable<ImmutableDictionary<string, Price>> sampled =
    Observable
        .Create<ImmutableDictionary<string, Price>>(o =>
        {
            var output = ImmutableDictionary<string, Price>.Empty;
            return
                source
                    .Do(x => output = output.SetItem(x.Key, x))
                    .Select(x => Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Select(y => output).StartWith(output))
                    .Switch()
                    .Subscribe(o);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

A hot observable won't keep any old values in memory but you could catch the last price of each known key yourself, for example in a dictionary.

Please refer to the following sample code.

```
Dictionary<string, double> _prices = new Dictionary<string, double>();

GetPrices()
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Subscribe(prices =>
    {
        if (prices != null && prices.Count > 0)
        {
            var grouped = prices.GroupBy(x => x.Key);
            foreach (var group in grouped)
                _prices[group.Key] = group.Last().Bid;
        }

        //print out the last quote of each known price key
        foreach (var price in _prices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key: " + price.Key + ", last price: " + price.Value);
        }
    });
```

It should print the last quote of each known key every second.

Comment: I think the business logic should be within the Observable, not the Subscription like presented

Comment: Business logic...? Read the question and the answer again.

Comment: The question is asking to start from a `IObservable<Price>` and it seems to want to produce a value every second. This doesn't do that.

Comment: Did you miss "Let's assume the IObservable is linked to an External Price Feed"? You certainly don't control when a hot price feed produces price ticks...

Comment: @mm8 the whole point of the solution (or Rx in general) is to control the hot Observable :)

Comment: @supertopi: In this case I guess the user wants to do something, whatever that is, with the latest known prices every second. The IObservable itself just "pushes" out the prices from the feed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a polished version of Shlomo's [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45826439/11178549), of maintaining the latest values per key using the `Scan` operator and an [`ImmutableDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2) as state. The custom operator below (`SampleByKey`) samples a sequence of key-bearing elements at a specific interval. Upon each sampling tick an `IDictionary<TKey, TSource>` is emitted, containing the latest values that have been emitted so far by each key.

```
public static IObservable<IDictionary<TKey, TSource>> SampleByKey<TSource, TKey>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    TimeSpan interval,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = default)
{
    return source
        .Scan(ImmutableDictionary.Create<TKey, TSource>(keyComparer),
            (dict, x) => dict.SetItem(keySelector(x), x))
        .Publish(published => Observable
            .Interval(interval)
            .WithLatestFrom(published, (_, dict) => dict)
            .TakeUntil(published.LastOrDefaultAsync()));
}
```

Usage example:

```
IObservable<IDictionary<string, Price>> sampled = priceFeed
    .SampleByKey(p => p.Key, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
```

In case that zero elements have been emitted by the `source` during two samplings, the same dictionary will be emitted consecutively.

This implementation is very similar with one I've posted previously in [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648135/generate-events-with-dynamically-changeable-time-interval/), about how to sample a sequence at a dynamically changeable time interval.

**Note:** I scraped my previous implementation ([Revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65402258/1)) as too complex and potentially leaky. Shlomo's approach is easier to understand and modify as needed.