# How to write a SelectManyLatest operator in Rx.NET and UniRx

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rx.net, unirx

`SelectManyLatest` is necessary operator.
But All Internet don't answer how you can write it.
So how?

`SelectManyLatest` is a [`FlatMapLatest`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) in other Rx Frameworks.
This operator like `SelectMany` but it complete previous subscription if new emit happens.

Comment: Your question should be detailed enough for someone to know what you are talking about based on the question alone without reading your answer.

Comment: Could you include in the question the signature of the `SelectManyLatest` operator, and describe its desirable behavior?

Comment: Are you searching for the [`Switch`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html) operator?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Partially! Switch is a combining operator but SelectManyLatest is transforming operator. I wrote an Answer bellow. It works as it should)

Comment: Well, saying that the `SelectManyLatest` operator is transforming, doesn't help me to the slightest to understand what this operator is supposed to do. Ηonestly I think that your question in its current state, is unlikely to be helpful to anyone.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The only difference between SelectMany and SelectManyLatest is it disposes previous subscription when new subscription happens.

Comment: That's what the `Switch` does. It unsubscribes from the previous inner sequence and subscribes to the next inner sequence. You said that `Switch` is a combining operator, which says nothing to me about why the `Switch` has not the functionality that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add as an Extension

```
public static IObservable<V> SelectManyLatest<T, V>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, IObservable<V>> selector)
{
    return source
        .Select(selector)
        .Switch();
}
```

Comment: This answer subscribes multiple times to the `value` sequence, with is a no-no for general purpose operators, because it can cause inconsistent behavior, depending on whether the sequence is cold or hot. This problem is usually solved easily with the `Publish` operator ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66710789/observable-getting-latest-value-in-intervals-until-source-finishes/66713533#66713533)).

Comment: Value will be completed when a source will emit. If you are sure that this is wrong, please write correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I can't write anything correctly when the specifications are unclear.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Ok, I understood! I used Switch incorrectly and I didn't get desired effect. I will write correctly in an Answer bellow. Thanks!

Comment: Oh! I can't add another Answer. I fixed current =)